# Output all instances from 1 to 8 where the length of the spelling of a number is greater than the length of the spelling of a value higher than it?

Tags: haskell, scope, ghci

I'm a complete Haskell noob and I've been trying to do this for an entire day now.

So one output could be:

Three,Six

(3 is less than 6 but the spelling of it is longer than the spelling of 6)

I came up with this in Haskell but the variables go out of scope, I don't really understand scope in Haskell yet. This might be completely wrong but any help is appreciated.

```
let numbers = [("One",1),("Two",2),("Three",3),("Four",4),("Five",5),("Six",6),("Seven",7),("Eight",8)]

[([ x | x <- numbers], [y | y <- numbers]) | length (fst x) > length (fst y), snd x < snd y]
```

Can someone help me to correct this nested list comprehension? Or even tell me if I can use a nested list comprehension at all?

To clarify:

I want to output a list of pairs, where the spelling of the first element in the pair is longer than the spelling of the second element in the pair, but also, the first element in the pair as a number, is less than the second element in the pair as a number.

Comment: "scope" just means the part of a program from which you can access a particular variable. It exists in every programming language (and is actually usually less visible in Haskell than in other languages, given that Haskell variables are immutable). Anyway, it's really not clear what you're trying to output (it appears to be a list of pairs of lists? and `[x | x <- numbers]` is identical to just `numbers`) - but the reason your code doesn't work is that `x` and `y` are only in scope inside the list comprehensions you're using them in.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yeah I want to output a list of pairs, where the spelling of the first element in the pair is longer than the spelling of the second element in the pair, but also, the first element in the pair as a number, is less than the second element in the pair as a number.

I understand scope in other languages, just not in Haskell. I'm trying to understand how I can use the values from the nested list comprehension, in the overall list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
[(y1, y2) | (x1, y1) <- numbers, (x2, y2) <- numbers, length x1 > length x2, y1 < y2]
```

That is, it's a list of pairs of numbers - with the requirements you specify. I'm not able to test this at a moment, I think it should work but let me know if you have any issues with it.

Your scope issues were because you were trying to do nested comprehensions and access variables from the inner comprehension in the outer one - this is not allowed, because a variable used inside a comprehension is only in scope in that particular comprehension.

I have also replaced your uses of `fst` and `snd` by explicit pattern-matching on the elements of the pair, which is almost always preferred because it's more explicit.